# How can I store various users in my json file for a discord.py command?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

This is my code, and the current problem is that it only saves the latest change to my users.json file.

```
@commands.command()
    async def command(self, ctx):
        userid = ctx.message.author.id
        with open('users.json', "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
            userdata = json.load(f)
        try:
            with open('users.json', "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
                userdata[str(userid)]["coins"] = userdata[str(userid)]["coins"] + 1
                json.dump(userdata, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
        except:
            with open('users.json', "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
                userdata = {}
                userdata[str(userid)] = {}
                userdata[str(userid)]["coins"] = 0
                json.dump(userdata, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Example: I use the command and this is what is stored in the file:

```
{
    "idnumber": {
        "coins": 0
    }
}
```

But if someone else does it my variable coins is replaced by theirs leaving just:

```
{
    "theiridnumber": {
        "coins": 0
    }
}
```

Any fix?

Comment: Where do you initialize `myballs` for a particular user? I think you have used a try-except block because it is not initialized?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat my bad, edited the question just now. "myballs" was basically "coins", but just the test variable i was working with that i changed to "coins" in the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it appears that you have used try-except just to see if a key is not present etc. This kind of usage is quite unnecessary (and needlessly complex too) considering you can do the same quite simply with various dictionary methods `get`, `setdefault` etc.
Try this:

```
@commands.command()
async def command(self, ctx):
    userid = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    with open('users.json', "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
        userdata = json.load(f)
    userdata.setdefault(userid, {}) # if key exists do nothing else set as dictionary, also returns value for key
    # dict.get(key, alternate) either gets the value for key or returns the alternate given
    userdata[userid]["coins"] = userdata[userid].get("coins", -1) + 1
    with open('users.json', "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
        json.dump(userdata, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved it. I have a doubt though, how can I do so that it sends a message if the user's corresponding id isn't in the json file?

Comment: use `if userid in userdata` and `else` instead of `userdata.setdefault(userid, {})`